# URL Builder/Query builder in Go

Tags: rest, url, go

I am interested in dynamically taking arguments from the user as input through a browser or a CLI to pass in those parameters to the REST API call and hence construct the URL dynamically using Go which is going to ultimately fetch me some JSON data.

I want to know some techniques in Go which could help me do that. One ideal way I thought was to use a map and populate it with arguments keys and corresponding values and iterate over it and append it to the URL string. But when it comes to dynamically taking the arguments and populating the map, I am not very sure how to do that in Go. Can someone help me out with some code snippet in Go?

Request example:

```
http://<IP>:port?api=fetchJsonData&arg1=val1&arg2=val2&arg3=val3.....&argn=valn
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

There's already [`url.URL`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) that handles that kind of things for you.

For http handlers (incoming requests) it's a part of [`http.Request`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) (access it with req.URL.Query()).

A very good example from the official [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#example_URL):

```
u, err := url.Parse("http://bing.com/search?q=dotnet")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
u.Scheme = "https"
u.Host = "google.com"
q := u.Query()
q.Set("q", "golang")
u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
fmt.Println(u)
```

Comment: This is a nice way. Thanks. Could you also suggest a way, where I could store the key-value pair in a map and then use that map to construct the URL ?

Comment: @psbits `url.Values` is a map (you can get a copy from u.Query()), you can use it to construct the URL then use `u := url.Parse("http://base.com/"); u.RawQuery = yourValues.Encode(); URL := u.String()`

Comment: Well, thanks . I did something like this - { urlMap := make(map[string]string)
 urlMap["arg1"] = "val1"
 urlMap["arg2"] = "val2"

 url.Scheme = "http"
 url.Host = ip + ":" + defaultPort
 q := url.Query()
 for k, _ := range urlMap {
  q.Set(k, urlMap[k])
 }
 url.RawQuery = q.Encode()

 fmt.Println(url)}

Comment: @psbits you don't have to, `url.Values` is defined as `type Values map[string][]string`, you can just use it directly.

Comment: I love how cheeky the doc example is :)

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17340#issuecomment-251537687

https://play.golang.org/p/XUctl_odTSb

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func someURL() string {
    url := url.URL{
        Scheme: "https",
        Host:   "example.com",
    }
    return url.String()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(someURL())
}
```

returns:

https://example.com

Answer (score 12):

[`url.Values{}`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#example-Values) provides an interface for building query params. You can construct inline and/or use `.Add` for dynamic properties:

```golang
queryParams := url.Values{
    "checkin":  {request.CheckIn},
    "checkout": {request.CheckOut},
}

if request.ReservationId {
    queryParams.Add("reservationId", request.ReservationId)
}

url := "https://api.example?" + queryParams.Encode() // checkin=...&checkout=...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

 partofUrl := &url.URL{
     Scheme: "https",
     Host: "test.dev",
     Path: "/abc",
}
fmt.Println(partofUrl.String()) //https://test.dev/abc
    
}
```