# Structuring HTTP POST request to include req query but q values in body of request

Tags: go

I'm currently attempting to make a POST request using the HTTP package in Go. In the body of the request, it needs a 'code' pulled from the query of the API call to complete the request.

However, I first need to declare the req to add the query URL values in to do this. So I'm stuck with declaring q as url.Values{}, passing that in to the body of my post, and then having to add the values after the initial HTTP declaration.

But because I'm passing q in to the request before adding these values, the request URL doesn't include them when I'm sending the request. So I'm essentially just sending a blank query (I think).

So how can I get around this and pass in the query details to my http request but access the query value?

Hopefully that makes sense - it's confusing!

Here's my code:

```
func Fetch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    client := &http.Client{}

    q := url.Values{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://auth.truelayer-sandbox.com/connect/token", strings.NewReader(q.Encode()))

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        fmt.Println("Error was not equal to nil at first stage.")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    q.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    q.Add("id", os.Getenv("ID"))
    q.Add("secret", os.Getenv("SECRET"))
    q.Add("redirect_uri", "https://callback.com")
    q.Add("query-param", req.URL.Query().Get("query-param"))

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending request to server")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    w.Write(respBody)

}
```

Comment: `req.URL.Query().Get("query-param")`  always evaluates to `""`. Did you intend to use `r.FormValue("query-param")` instead?

Comment: No - I’m trying to access a query passed in from a callback in the URL of the API request. The user doesn’t fill in a form, so figured this would be how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL Builder/Query builder in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984420/url-builder-query-builder-in-go)

Comment: I am confused about which URL you are referring to. The function handles request `r` and creates request `req`.    Which request do you want to get the parameter from?  The URL for `req` does not have query parameters.

Comment: The HTTP request gets called via a serverless function endpoint, which has a query in it that needs to get passed into the API function built here. So imagine: https://exampleurl.com/api/blabla?code=ghdjvldjgjd - I need to access the 'code' here to access the TrueLayer API in my function request. This URL is what gets called to trigger the function.

Comment: D'oh! Just realised what you meant Cerise... I can access the query from the 'r' in initial function. Think that's it. My bad!